# how to set cookie on ".localhost" from express/node application so that it can be accessed from "something.localhost"

Tags: node.js, express

I am having a node/express application that runs at www.localhost:1234. Now I want to set a httponly cookie from express at domain ".localhost". and want to access it on subdomains like "something.localhost:1234" or "something.localhost:1234". I tried doing this but not working.

**js**

```
let options = {
  path:'/*',
  domain:'.localhost',
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
};
res.cookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', options);
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can set cookies for subdomain.

Subdomain is a child node of **root domain** when DNS resolves the tree. To be a valid **root domain**, it should have 2 parts separated by a dot.

So, `something.localhost` doesn't make it a sub-domain of `localhost`, even though `something.localhost` resolves to same thing as `localhost`.

**Solution,**
Add following in `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1 app.com ## <- Becomes root domain
127.0.0.1 api.app.com
127.0.0.1 something.app.com
```

**ACTION:** Now, load your web application using `app.com:4000` and hit corresponding api using `api.app.com:4001/users` (Server running on PORT 4001)

But now, the cookie stored will be corresponding to domain `api.app.com`. To resolve this, you need to set domain in cookie as `app.com`(whatever your root domain is).

**Solution:**

I'm using `express-session 1.16.2`, My config looks like

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'some-key',
  name: '_somecookie',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { domain: 'app.com', secure: false }, // <- THIS, set domain as 'app.com'
  store: myRedisStore,
}));
```

Now perform your **ACTION** again. You should see a cookie corresponding to domain `.app.com` which is shared by all web apps under **root domain** `app.com`, eg: Check cookies under `app.com:4000` and `api.app.com:4000` or `something.app.com:4000`.

[image]
[image]

**Note 1:**
Ensure to clear any cookie that exist corresponding to domain `api.app.com`  as result of performing **ACTION** 1st time (Check by opening `api.app.com:4000` in browser), otherwise, according to your server implementing, you might not be re-setting the cookie if it already exists.

**Note 2**
Since `app.com` is making http request to `api.app.com`, ensure setting CORS header correctly, eg:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://app.com:4000');
```

Use [express cors middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) for easily whitelisting multiple subdomains/domains.

-------- Adding to this answer --------

It is very important to mention that you have to add to this request from front-end side:
`{ credentials: "include" }`
example:
`{ method: "POST", body: {}, credentials: "include" }`